# FCM push notifications FLUTTER when app is terminated

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to receive push notifications on ANDROID from the Firebase console when the app is terminated but I get nothing (I have onResume, onMessage and onLaunch callback listeners but  I don’t even want to handle them in the app yet) I’d just like to get them to show In the tray or lock screen. Is  there some Android configuration required?

Comment: You can test it from Postman: Check it out [Test FCM Notification with Postman](https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3)

Comment: there is no onResume, onLaunch, i think you are using older version of firebase_messaging, try with latest version. and also firebase recommend to use 
HTTP V1 instead of legacy api

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Answer (score 6):

first answer, I hope will be good.

As you can see [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#message-types) notifications are handled with onBackgroundMessage even if the app is terminated. Maybe your problem is that you are not sending a Notification but a "Data only" message. In that case you have to set the field `"priority": "high"`

Also, with the latest release of Flutter and [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) the methods onResume, onMessage and onLaunch are deprecated. You should substitute them with onMessage, onMessageOpened, onBackground, but you can find definitely more info with the [official documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications)

Comment: thanks. i always forget this

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to @samUser1 answer.
When app is terminated this code will handle events.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
```

And outside main function parse it. The example below uses AwesomeNotifications package.
https://github.com/rafaelsetragni/awesome_notifications/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  final res = await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
    content: NotificationContent(
      id: Random().nextInt(1000000),
      channelKey: 'channel_name',
      title: 'Hello!',
      body: 'World!',
      notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default,
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: with this configuration on the iOS side the whole main function is running whenever any data only notification is sent with app is on killed mode. This is causing side effects as runApp is running. Any way in which we can run only the high level function